# Tips for Html parsing and web driving with clojure?

Tags: clojure, html-parsing, clojure-contrib

I want to automate filling in data on a website using clojure.

For this I want to query elements of webpages and create http requests. I have been looking at using HttpUnit and contrib.clojure.zip-filter.xml. So far neither approach feels right.

Are there alternative libraries to aid with this task?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like the perfect use case for [Enlive](http://github.com/cgrand/enlive) (characterised by the author -- Christophe Grand -- as "a selector-based (à la CSS) templating and transformation system for Clojure").

See e.g. the [How to select nth element of particular type in enlive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695701/how-to-select-nth-element-of-particular-type-in-enlive) SO question -- and my answer to it -- for an example of use. For more in-depth information, there's David Nolen's [excellent tutorial](http://github.com/swannodette/enlive-tutorial).

Comment: Not that you couldn't use zippers... Here's another SO question which might be relevant if you choose to go the zipper route: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872921/insertions-into-zipper-trees-on-xml-files-in-clojure

Comment: Enlive rocks. Highly recommend it. Zippers would be my second choice but Enlive is way better than a zipper.